# What does a country related domain extension involve?

Tags: domains, domain-extension

i want to buy a domain name, with an extension in .es (Spain) to make a shorter url. But does having a ".es" website means i have to host my website in spain ? What does it actually mean to have a country related domain extension ? (in terms of hosting, legislation, terms of use ... ?)

I know some websites like bit.ly, youtu.be, etc... are international websites, but did they do something to do so ? (like having a company registered in that country)

Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the rules are potentially different for each [country TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain). They are set by the corresponding governments.

There is a wide variation from "anything goes as long as you pay us" to "you must live in this country"(for example).

Most don't have restrictions on the physical location of the hosting server but they often have other restrictions.

Remember that the country where the hosting server is physically located will have legal jurisdiction over the physical server and might have very different laws to the country that controls the TLD you are using.

You should contact your preferred authorised registrar for each TLD you are interested in and ask them what the requirements are.

The rules for the [.es TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.es) are controlled by [www.dominios.es](http://www.dominios.es).

According to [their rules](http://www.dominios.es/dominios/en/todo-lo-que-necesitas-saber/sobre-registros-de-dominios/quien-puede)

> You can apply for any of the following ".es" domains from any country
>   in the world as long as you maintain ties to Spain:
>
> Individuals and legal entities and organisations without legal entity
>   with ties to Spain may apply for any ".es"and/or ".com.es" domain. For
>   ".nom.es" domains, individuals entities with ties to Spain may apply.
>   Entities, institutions or groups, with or without legal entity, that
>   are non-profit making and have ties to Spain may register ".org.es"
>   domains.
>
> The ".gob.es" and ".edu.es" domains may be applied for by Public
>   Bodies and Entities and Institutions related to Education and Research
>   in Spain, respectively.
>
> The ".gob.es" domains are reserved for Spanish Public Administrations
>   and the Public Law entities within their sphere. Entities,
>   institutions and groups, with or without legal entity, that are
>   officially recognised and undertake activities related to education or
>   research in Spain may obtain ".edu.es" domains.
>
> YOU CAN REGISTER AN ".ES" DOMAIN FROM ANYWHERE IN THE WORLD, AS LONG
>   AS YOU HAVE TIES TO SPAIN!

Comment: Well, except my family is from Spain (and I still have some over there), i don't have any ties to the country. But then, what does "ties" means when it's written `Individuals and legal entities and organisations without legal entity with ties to Spain may apply for any ".es" domain`

Comment: you really need to ask the registrar, no one else can give you an up to date authoritative answer. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is no problem at all to host your website anywhere, that is what DNS is all about.

You would just point the nameservers for the domain to the hosting service.

Comment: Ok thanks. I always get a bit mixed up about all that. But then (on a legal point of view) is my website under spanish laws and restrictions or under my host's country laws ?

Comment: The site comes under the jurisdiction of the where the hosting server is located.  Hence thepiratebay being in Sweden for years as their copyright laws let them get away with it.

The .es domain regulator might decide to kill the domain if you are breaking a Spanish law.